# Pandas - fill a column with value from another column only when MULTIPLE COLUMNs are null

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis, data-cleaning

#### I have a Pandas DataFrame like this:

```
   a      b    c      x    a1     b1     c1     x1
0  aa    ba   ca      9    NaN    NaN    NaN    1
1  ab    bb   cb      9    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
2  ac    bc   cd    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
3  ad    bd   cd      9    1      NaN    NaN    NaN
4  ae    be   ce      9    NaN    2      NaN    12
5  af    bf   cf      9    NaN    NaN    3      14
6  ag    bg   cg      9    3      NaN    1      45
```

#### I want to do:

```
   a      b    c      x    a1     b1     c1     x1
0  aa    ba   ca      9    NaN    NaN    NaN    1
1  ab    bb   cb      9    NaN    NaN    NaN    9
2  ac    bc   cc    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
3  ad    bd   cd      9    1      NaN    NaN    NaN
4  ae    be   ce      9    NaN    2      NaN    12
5  af    bf   cf      9    NaN    NaN    3      14
6  ag    bg   cg      9    3      NaN    1      45
```

#### Explanation:

**row 0:** I don't want the replacement to happen, when there's already a value in `x1`, and even when all of the `a1`, `b1` and `c1` are `NaN`s.
**rows 1 & 2:** I want to fill column `x1` with whatever is in `x`, only and only when columns `a1`, `b1` and `c1` are `NaN`s.
**rows 3, 4, 5 & 6:** I want the column `x1` to stay as is, when any one or two columns from `a1`, `b1` and `c1` are `NaN`s.

Is there an efficient way to do this operation?

---

I have tried as shown in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53389699/pandas-dataframe-copy-the-contents-of-a-column-if-it-is-empty/53389782#53389782) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53389699/pandas-dataframe-copy-the-contents-of-a-column-if-it-is-empty/53389783#53389783) stackoverflow answers, but I get broadcast error, presumably because I am trying to do the check on multiple columns.

Here's what I have tried:

```
np.where(np.isnan(df[['a1', 'b1', 'c1']].values), df['x'].values, df['x1'].values)
```

and my error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-bb6a0f9faf18> in <module>
----> 1 np.where(np.isnan(df[['a', 'b', 'c']].values), df['x'].values, df['x1'].values)

<__array_function__ internals> in where(*args, **kwargs)

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (176213,6) (176213,) (176213,)
```

Comment: mr ecker, it is a mistake that i made, when i am trying to mask and copy-paste data. but, what i want to do is i what i wrote. i have fixed it now.

Comment: Shouldn't row 1 be `9` in `x1` then?

Comment: yes, i fixed it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use [`any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html#pandas-dataframe-any) on axis=1:

```
df['x1'] = np.where(df[['a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'x1']].any(axis=1), df['x1'], df['x'])
```

`df`:

```
    a   b   c    x   a1   b1   c1    x1
0  aa  ba  ca  9.0  NaN  NaN  NaN   1.0
1  ab  bb  cb  9.0  NaN  NaN  NaN   9.0
2  ac  bc  cd  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN
3  ad  bd  cd  9.0  1.0  NaN  NaN   NaN
4  ae  be  ce  9.0  NaN  2.0  NaN  12.0
5  af  bf  cf  9.0  NaN  NaN  3.0  14.0
6  ag  bg  cg  9.0  3.0  NaN  1.0  45.0
```

---

Another option via [@Jon Clements♦](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67722946/pandas-fill-a-column-with-value-from-another-column-only-when-multiple-columns/67723089?noredirect=1#comment119704055_67723089):

```
df.loc[~df[['a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'x1']].any(1), 'x1'] = df['x']
```

---

The reason for negating `any` instead of using `all` is that `any` will consider `NaN` as falsey, while `all` considers `NaN` as truthy:

```
pd.Series([np.nan, np.nan]).any()  # False
pd.Series([np.nan, np.nan]).all()  # True
```

Comment: Could probably do: `x.loc[~x[['a1', 'b1', 'c1']].any(1), 'x1'] = x['x']`...

Comment: That also works. I'll add that option to my answer as well.

Comment: shouldn't it be something like .all(axis=1), instead of any?

Comment: So `all` evaluates NaN as "Truthy" (`pd.Series([np.nan, np.nan]).all()  # True` while `any` evaluates nan as "Falsey" `pd.Series([np.nan, np.nan]).any()  # False`. Which is why we both negated `any`. Either via `~` or having `x1` be the true condition in `np.where`

Comment: mr ecker, there's been a mistake. as mentioned in the first row of my example, i don't want the replacement to be done, when there's a value in x1, i want the replacement to happen only when there's a null in x1 as well as in 'a1', 'b1', 'c1'. will you please be able to update your answer for this, i will update my question too. thanks.

Comment: @NaveenKumar Super easy fix. Just add 'x1' to the collist. Updated my answer.

Comment: Huge thanks @HenryEcker and @ JonClements for your time and help.